# Using where clause to query date ranges in ArcPy

Tags: arcpy

I would like to query a feature classes date range.  For instance, if there is data within a 2 day range then I would like to print true or do something else.  I thought arcpy.Exist would do the job, but I am missing something here.  I guess my arcpy.Exist is only seeing if the variable exists, how would I check to see if the actual where clause is True for my feature layer?

```
query = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "QueryLayer", """Date BETWEEN '2014-02-16 16:53:25' AND  '2014-02-17 18:53:25'""")


try:
    query

finally:
    if arcpy.Exists(query):
        print "true"
    else:
        print "no data"
```

Comment: Note: [Cross-posted to Esri's GeoNet](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/140029)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arcpy.Exists()` will check for the existence of datasets, so it should always return true given the way you have it set up here, because `query` will exist whether there are records in it or not.

You could use `arcpy.GetCount_management()`.

```
query = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "QueryLayer", """Date BETWEEN '2014-02-16 16:53:25' AND  '2014-02-17 18:53:25'""")
count = arcpy.GetCount_management(query).getOutput(0)
if count > 0:
    #do something: at this point you know that the query returned at least one record.
```

Based on @nmpeterson's answer in [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/139232/using-python-to-count-records-and-show-difference), you may want to try this alternative method for getting the count (if you're using 10.1+), may be faster:

```
count = sum((1 for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(query, ['OID@'])))
```

Comment: Hi Mr. Adam, what is "OID@" I am not understanding this syntax.  I figured a search cursor would be quicker as I don't need a feature layer.

Comment: "OID@" is the standard way to get the object ID field with the .da cursors.  In this case, the cursor only includes one field, "OID@" and it is a field that is guaranteed to exist in every feature class or shapefile.  So this `sum` operation is performed on a list of 1's, as many 1's as there are rows in the cursor, i.e. records in the feature class.  More info on using OID@: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//018w00000011000000

Answer (score 1):

This solution works better.

```
cursor = arcpy.SearchCursor(fc,"""Date BETWEEN '2014-02-16 16:53:25' AND  '2015-02-17 16:53:25'""" )
for row in cursor:
 print(row.getValue("Date"))


if row.getValue("Date") < datetime.datetime.now():
    print "true"
```